# FORTICLIENT SSL VPN in windows and linux which can't ping each others

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, ssl

I am using a windows 10 and linux successfully connected to SSL VPN.
windows (10.212.134.200)
linux (16.04) (10.212.134.201)

I can use my linux to ping windows and local ip but I can't ping my linux by windows or other local ip computers.

I have try to turn off linux firewall already and enble the NAT.

In addition, linux network is using mobile network (sim 4G).

I have try to insert that sim card into mobile phone and connect to SSL VPN and then my windows can ping it but once I insert back to linux one, I can't ping the linux even I connected successfully.